# Custom pagination in datatables using count as parameter

Tags: javascript, datatable, pagination

I am using datatable(datatables.net) to display rows of data. 
For performance issues...instead of loading hundreds of rows , based upon the filters(10 rows, 15 rows) i fetch only only so much data to feed into the datatable using my custom paging stored procedure. In addition , the Sp retrieves the total count of rows, so that using this total count , we could somehow display appropriate pagination. Let me illustrate: suppose, based on a given set of conditions , the rows (total) retrieved are 100. But the datatable filter is set to display only 10 rows, the SP , will fetch only those 10 rows , and the count is computed separately as 100. When displaying data , the user sees only the 10 rows , however since there are 90 more as per condition, i need to show appropriate pagination. 
Could someone please guide me as to how to accomplish this as i am very new to datatables and need to do this ASAP.

thanks, Philip

Comment: Are you looking to do this server side or client side?

Comment: As per my knowledge the datatables do have attributes to show custom pagination like full numbers etc, but they are just formats.

Comment: @snareChops I believe i might have to pass it to the client side , as the datatable needs to render this

Comment: What is your server side language? If you need it done quickly it might be faster to create the appropriate html on the server, or is this already wired up through AJAX calls?

Comment: yes its already created through ajax calls, just need to customize it for my requirement, server side is asp.net using c#

Comment: @Snarechops , any approach is welcome

Answer (score 0):

If your AJAX is already wired up then it would probably be faster to do this client side, although if you could do the calculation of how many pages needed and then that takes a little work off the client, but is also very simple.

Looking through the documentation I see what you mean that the paging options are not quite what you need. It looks like it is meant to hold all of the data and then just page itself.

So... You might need to create your own paging outside of this datatable and then just reload it based on paging parameters manually. This usually take a bit of work, but seems very possible.

First turn the paging on the datatable off using the option:

```
$('table').datatable({paging:false});
```

Then create a custom paging section that will submit to the url to reload the table with new data. Many tutorials, helpers, libraries, plugins, and other resources could help jump start things a little bit.

Though, I haven't seen your server code to see how or if this may be easier on the server than the client, but in my opinion, the only way to do this is sending that `COUNT(*)` information to the view and rendering the html for it, either through javascript or just basic HTML.

Comment: Awesome, let me know if you need any further pointers. Good luck!